# Azure Powershell: Restore Services backup restore location

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I can issue a request to start a recovery job using `Restore-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem`, which will restore the given recovery point (in this case, a VHD) to the storage account provided.  Is there a way to derive the location that the blob is being written to from the AzureRM API or Powershell commandlets?

Getting the recovery job:

```
$recoveryJob = Restore-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem `
  -RecoveryPoint $recoveryPoint `
  -StorageAccountName $storageAccount.name `
  -StorageAccountResourceGroupName $storageAccount.resourceGroupName
```

... but `$recoveryJob` does not have the storage destination.  `Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupJobDetails` does not provide this information either, and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I don't understand, you want to write to specific blob?

Comment: No, you don't have the option to write to a specific blob.  I want to know the name the command picks.